# ORA-00001 using oracle sequences and hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am this strategy of generation for IDs im my table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HGCTRAMITES")
@Getter
@Setter
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_HGCTRAMITES", sequenceName="SEQ_HGCTRAMITES")
@ToString
public class Tramite {
```

My column primary key it is like this:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_HGCTRAMITES")
    private Integer codigo;
```

This sequence and this table already it is  use perother app, this table already have data.

I am using Oracle 11g, my dialect hibernate: it is `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

In log console, the hibernate call the query for next sequence, but i receive the error: ORA-00001: restrição exclusiva (HELPDESK.PK_HGCTRAMITES) violada.

My table have only columns `codigo` for primary key.

Why hibernate is searching the id that it is alread exists ?

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        seq_hgctramites.nextval 
    from
        dual
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably this:

> This sequence and this table already it is use perother app

Do you have a guarantee that other app uses the same sequence `SEQ_HGCTRAMITES` for generating primary keys, **in the same way that Hibernate does**?

Hibernate will, by default, expect the sequence to increment by 50, and use the numbers from `n-50` to `n` for populating the ids, where `n` is the last value generated by the sequence.

If you know, for instance, that the other app expects the sequence to increment by 1, and simply uses the last sequence value for consecutive ids, you should use `@SequenceGenerator(..., incrementBy = 1)` to mimic that behavior. To get out of your current predicament, you will also need to forward the sequence so that neither app tries to use an id which is already present in the table (you can simply keep selecting `nextval` from the sequence until it is larger than any id already present).

If both apps use JPA, then keeping the `incrementBy` parameter in sync should do the trick (the part about forwarding the sequence still holds, though).